# Push Object in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, object

I was wondering if it's possible to push values to an object like in Arrays:

```
array.push("value");
```

I wanna give each color a letter like a, b, c, ..
It should be like:

```
var colors = { "a" : "ffffff", "b" : "000000" };
```

How can I add now other colors with letters to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple as:

```
colors["c"] = "ff0000";
colors["d"] = "00ff00";
colors["e"] = "0000ff";
// etc
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or even `colors.c = "ff0000";` etc. - Object is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to make a selection from an Object, a Dictionary or an Array. But if you want to use those "a","b","c" as keys you will want to use an Object or a Dictionary instance.

```
var colors:Object = {};
colors["a"] = "etc.";
colors["b"] = "etc.";
// or
var colors:Object = {};
colors.a = "etc.";
colors.b = "etc.";
// or
var colors:Object = {a:"etc.",b:"etc"};
```